# Call onActivityResult when stop button in video capture is clicked

Tags: java, android

I am using `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` to capture video. When it is done and Stop button is clicked I want to call `onActivityResult` in my Activity.

```
    String mCurrentPhotoPath = video.getAbsolutePath();

    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File videoFile = video;
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (videoFile != null) {
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    videoUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(videoUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

This is calling my Video Recorder. How can I trigger my `onActivityResult`. Can I somehow override the onStop click in the recorder.

P.S. I have an image capture that is working fine, but it has a Discard/Save buttons. On Save clicked it comes back to the `onActivityResult`. Regards to all stackoverflowers.

Comment: ...or you can just write the code you want to do in `onActivityResult` in another method and call it from the stop button?

Comment: Thats fine, but where is the onStop method of video capture.

Comment: How can I implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.
When the user either completes or cancels the video recording session, the `onActivityResult()` method of the calling activity will be called. You can't access another app from yours.
And there are dozen of different camera apps, that potentially can process your request.

You can directly access `Camera` api and implement this feature inside your app. But you really can't expect other apps will do exactly what you want.